# API for user next achievement/badge requirement?

Tags: feature-request, api

If you look at your user profile you can see:

```
visited  x days, x consecutive
```

So for the achievement/badge "Fanatic - Visited the site each day for 100 consecutive day" I can calculate the number of days I still need to achieve this.

Is there more API calls one could request to improve achievements/badges?

Example:

- How many more up-votes in this tag before silver badge
- How many votes left before hitting the maximum 40 votes in a day
- How many posts have I edited

Etc...

maybe even more information on how you earned the achievement/badge

There could be a ton more but I hope you get the idea

Comment: Your profile shows number of upvotes in tags and number of votes over the day.

Comment: is there and API call for this?

Comment: As far as I can tell the whole user profile part of this question is a red herring; that's not an API call either. You're just asking for API routes that expose badge progress?

Comment: well an API for more in-depth user info for achievements/badges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) if you haven't already.

Comment: yeah I've been playing around with it but not all the user information is there that I want

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Perhaps you could revise your question to ask for this information to be added to the API?

Comment: I tagged it as a feature-request, or is this not enough?

Comment: Well, it sounds a little too vague right now. Instead of "Is there more API calls one could request to improve achievements/badges?", I would say "I would like to have the following calls added to the API," followed by a list of your ideal formats described just like the calls on the StackExchange API page. I personally like the idea of an API to find the answer to "How many posts have I edited?", but instead of "How many votes left before hitting the maximum 40 votes in a day?" I would just ask "How many votes have I used today?" and, similarly, "How many up-votes in this tag?"

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore.